# how EPROCESS DirBase generated maybe "VAD tree root"?

Tags: windbg, windows-kernel

i dump some process data.
I got DirBase value as 00030000 
How windows generate this value ?
Any AVL Tree data structure at the begining of kernel gives this data?
I want to learn how process is created internally on kernel.
What kind of global variables assigns DirBase , ObjectTable  etc values.

Here is some sample windbg:
!process fb667a00 7
PROCESS fb667a00 Cid: 0002  Peb: 00000000 ParentCid: 0000
  DirBase: 00030000 ObjectTable: e1000f88 TableSize: 112.

```
When a process created by system.
System creates new pagedirectory for process and assigns a number to process page directory.
How can windows assigns that number ? is there an AVL Tree data structure that has free page tables and busy page tables trees.
And system allocates one page directory from that AVL Tree ?
There is no documentation how this mechanism works ?
I want to learn how page directory  gets its data ?
```

Answer (score 0):

DirBase is a physical address of a page directory.
Each process has own page directory, it is placed in the struct KPROCESS::DirectoryTableBase. When OS activates a process, the value from KPROCESS::DirectoryTableBase is loaded to CR3 register.

Page directory has a structure descripbed in Intel Developer Manual
http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging

Comment: how page directory  is generated ? its just counter for every new process ?

Comment: Page directory is generated by OS, it is not a counter. It is a set of physical pages. Begin from reading the link

Comment: I doubt its a "counter". The OS must find a free set of phyiscal pages that can serve the purposes (each single page table is one page long, except PDPT I think). But as said above, page directories and page tables are data structures specific to processor, not to the operating sytem, so Intel's manuals are of a great help here.