# How page directory is generated on Windows kernel on process creation

Tags: windbg, windows-kernel

how page directory is generated on Windows kernel ?
GDT setups memory limits for user memory layout.
But i want to learn how windows internally setups process page directory & VAD tree

Comment: Related: [How EProcess Dirbase generated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438679/how-eprocess-dirbase-generated-maybe-vad-tree-root)

Comment: its not answered there

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote "related" and not "duplicate of"

Comment: You want to understand the Windows internals in more details. I can recommend the book with the exact same name: [Windows Internals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx). I think it will answer many of your questions.

Comment: I see people downvoting this. Perhaps you can include a few lines where you describe what you know so far (e.g. which kernel objects) and at which step an answer should begin and what level of detail you expect. Also, what research you have done and which websites you found about that topic and why the information contained there is not enough yet.

Comment: Describe the problem you're having rather than your proposed solution. What is the problem that makes you think that you need to understand how the kernel constructs page tables in order to solve it? Win32 abstracts out page tables from applications. (For example, PowerPC and IA-64 use inverted page tables, which are very different from x86 direct page tables. But you don't have to worry about this. Win32 abstracts it out.)

Comment: Well, obtain a copy of Windows Research Kernel (WRK) – a source code of the ntoskrnl.exe module for WIndows Server 2003. I won't advise you where to get the package since its AFAIK available only for universities that have an agreement with Microsoft. You can study then, how all the things are implemented. W2k3 is an old system but you should get a clue how VADs and other memory manager stuff are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not use the GDT to isolate user mode from kernel mode on the x86, it uses per-page protection in the page tables. Check the Windows Internals book for details.